# How to get a ancestor node with a specific tag name

Tags: javascript, yui3

How I get the ancestor of a Yahoo UI node of a specific kind? For example, if I have a input element...

```
var node = A.one('input#_new_WAR_localizededitorportlet_test1');
```

I want to get its enclosing form. I know how to get the parent node:

```
var parent = node.get('parentNode');
```

but not how to (elegantly) go through the tree until reaching the form. For now I am using this

```
while (node.get('tagName').toLowerCase() != 'form') {
    node = node.get('parentNode');
}
```

but it is not a really succinct way of doing it.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `ancestor()` method:

```
node.ancestor('form')
```